# как скачать zip с ftp по маске?

Tags: c#

я указываю файл руками а хотелось бы чтобы он сам заходил в папку и качал оттуда все zip файлы начинающиеся с определенных символов.
так как я новичек в C# не могу додуматься как делать(

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые FTP серверы поддерживают фильтры по маскам, но не все, и, вероятно, лучше это делать самому, т.е. получить список всех файлов, а дальше отфильтровать каким-либо способом:

```
public static void Main ()
{
    var ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://localhost/");
    ftpRequest.Credentials =new NetworkCredential("LOGIN","PASSWORD");

    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    var response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    var Files = new List<string>();

    string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
        Files.Add(line);
        line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    }
    streamReader.Close();

    foreach (var F in Files)
        if (F.StartsWith("n") && (F.EndsWith(".zip")))
            Console.WriteLine(F);
}
```

См. также этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282753/ftp-directory-partial-listing-with-wildcards)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!=) все понятно и работает)